# add new user to external ldap in wso2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can anyone give me a sample program or any blog to add, update and delete users/roles on external user store in wso2 Identity Server. I configured external ldap as apacheDS in wso2 Identity Server successfully and authenticate users also. But my problem is I am unable to add, update, and delete users/roles in external ldap using wso2 Identity Server.

I am using latest wso2 Identity Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SCIM endpoints to manage users and roles, Please go through the following article.
http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS410/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+SCIM+Service+Provider

Answer (score 0):

you can use SCIM. check the following blogs they can help

- [pavithramadurangi.blogspot.com](http://pavithramadurangi.blogspot.com/2013/07/adding-users-to-wso2-identity-server.html)
- [sureshatt.blogspot.com](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2013/06/scim-user-provisioning-with-wso2.html)